# usage function from formatR removes white space unexpectedly

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-markdown, formatr

The `usage` function from [formatr](/questions/tagged/formatr) removes white space unexpectedly. See the example below:

```
library(formatR)
library(tidyverse)
usage(
    FUN           = inner_join
  , width         = getOption("width")
  , tidy          = c(TRUE, FALSE)[1]
  , output        = c(TRUE, FALSE)[1]
  , indent.by.FUN = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , fail          = c("warn", "stop", "none")
)

inner_join(x, y, by = NULL, copy = FALSE, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), ..., keep = FALSE)
```

However, I want something like this:

```
inner_join(
  x,
  y,
  by = NULL,
  copy = FALSE,
  suffix = c(".x", ".y"),
  ...,
  keep = FALSE
)
```

Comment: What in tarnation is this `c(T, F0[1]`? LOL, just write true or false. Also pick one option for fail.

Comment: FALSE is the default.  What are you thinking NULL would do?

Comment: @Elin that's a  typo. The question is not about `inner_join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trial and error with `width` will get you close to what you want:

```r
usage(
  FUN           = inner_join
  , width         = 12
  , tidy          = TRUE
  , output        = TRUE
  , indent.by.FUN = TRUE
  , fail          = "none"
)

#> inner_join(
#>            x,
#>            y,
#>            by = NULL,
#>            copy = FALSE,
#>            suffix = c(".x", ".y"),
#>            ...,
#>            keep = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks @M-- for useful answer. I want to use this output in Quarto document. Wondering if it possible to get colored output.

Comment: @MYaseen208 It's commented out because I used `reprex` package. You should be fine.